# Is there "magic" in the STL?

Tags: c++, stl, std

Let me start with explaining what I mean with "magic". I will use two examples from Java:

1. Every class inherits (directly or indirectly) the `Object` class.
2. Operator overloading is not supported by Java but the `+` operator is defined for `String` objects.

This means that it is impossible to make an implementation of the `Object` and `String` classes in pure(*) Java. Now this is what I mean with "magic": to make an implementation of these classes, you will need some special support from the compiler.

What I always liked about C++ is that, as far as I know, there is no such "magic" going on in the STL, i.e. it is possible to implement the STL in pure C++.

Now my question is: is this true? Or are there parts of the STL that cannot be implemented in pure C++ and need some "magic"/special compiler support?

---

(*) With "pure" I mean without using any class libraries.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing I believe. STL = Standard Template Library and it's in pure C++. You don't need to implement STL because it's already there. Did u mean template / generic classes instead? Or did you mean instantiating a particular instance of an STL container?

Comment: Software is never based on magic. However a good software can create illusion of 'magic'

Comment: @Vite: I know the STL is part of the standard but like my footnote says, with pure I mean without any libraries.

Comment: @Job: I think the confusion is stemming from your use of the word "magic." Describing it as "needing compiler/language support" would likely eliminate most of the confusion.

Comment: @greyfade: Added your suggestion. However, I think I pointed out what I mean with "magic".

Comment: I have seen some compilers add special tags and do some "magic" when interpreting them, but this has always just been so that they can output better warning/error messages. In the end, it never had any effect on the compiled code, just extra info for the coder (though many compilers don't do anything special at all with STL).

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." (A.C. Clarke)

Comment: @Job Like i mentioned in my question, did u mean 'template' class rather than STL. STL means it is a library and it is a class library. So your notion of 'pure' seemed a bit confusing.

Comment: @Vite: No I *do* mean STL. I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're confused about.

Comment: I think your question is "can STL be implemented in C++"? I think a broader question is more interesting: "can the standard C++ libraries be implemented in C++?" that includes the C runtime.

Comment: Edited to remove soap-box-ware, voted to reopen.

Comment: @bmargulies: Why did you remove that part from my question? I think it gives a good example of what I mean with "magic". Also, how is this subjective?

Comment: @bmargulies: I will do a rollback. I have to say I find it kind of rude to make such big changes to a question. And if you really think there is a good reason to do so, please make sure to not introduce any errors! E.g. The first sentence is missing a word and the footnote is not referenced anymore. /rant. Also, my intro is not meant to be flaming (like you mention in your edit) but just an explanation of what I mean with "magic".

Comment: Job, your question is argumentative.  I would have left it with the edit, but now that you've rolled back, I am voting to close again.

Comment: @Aaronaught: If you think it's argumentative, please give a reason for it so I can edit it in a way I'm also comfortable with. I still think the question is *very* objective. The fact that I dislike the given points about Java *might* be argumentative, although it's just my opinion. I do not say there is something wrong with Java.

Comment: @Job it was closed because 5 people found your anti-Java complaining unnecessary and inappropriate. After it was closed, I edited it to make it less objectionable. Now that you've rolled it back, it may now be closed again.

Comment: @bmargulies: No, it was closed because five people found it subjective, which it clearly isn't. That's why I rolled back your changes. Now, if those people (including you) would have told me they where offended by what you call "anti-Java complaining" (instead of voting to close without a word), all this hassle could have been avoided and I would have removed the offending part (which is what I have done now). By the way, like I said in another comment, I never meant to sound "anti-Java". I just meant to explain what I mean with "magic".

Comment: @Job:  Your use of "STL" is confusing.  There was, back in the 1990s, something called the "Standard Template Library", which was implemented in plain C++ as it existed at the time.  Most of the STL was absorbed into the standard C++ libraries, and so the STL itself is not in most modern implementations.  Your question about a C++0x STL is flat wrong; since the STL is essentially obsolete, there are no new versions of it.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the feedback! Would you suggest replacing all occurrences of "STL" with "C++ Standard Library"?

Comment: @bmargulies:  After quickly going through the edit record, I fail to see any Java-bashing.  Job has mentioned one feature he likes, which C++03 has, to some extent, and Java doesn't.  He does not make claims for the general superiority of one, and doesn't even say he dislikes Java.  This is about as innocuous an opinion one can have about computer languages, and has the virtue of being objective (given his opinion on compiler magic).  There's more argumentation in here than I like, but it isn't clear to me that that's Job's fault.

Comment: @Job:  I'd probably describe it as the containers, iterators, and algorithms part.  The C++ standard library does require some "magic".  For example, you can't do input without a library routine that reads something from a file, so you can't start with C++ without library and write the I/O parts of the library.

Comment: @David: But I used to think that the STL was the complete standard C++ library. So I'm also interested in any "magic" needed in other parts than the containers. Would it be too big a change to replace STL with Standard Library?

Comment: @David: It's usually pretty safe to assume that when people say "the STL", they mean the subset of the C++ standard library which is based on the STL". Pretending to be confused doesn't really gain anyone anything. Yes, everyone uses the term "STL" incorrectly, and so what? The human brain is good enough at dealing with ambiguities to sort that one out. I'd say "STL" is a bit more convenient to say than "the containers, iterators and algorithms part of the C++ standard library"...

Comment: There we go again... Could one of the closers please explain why you think this is subjective?

Comment: @Job:  I'd like to know myself.  This looks like a programming question with solid and objective answers.  It's a good question.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: I originally voted to close before the recent edits.  I'm fine with this version of the question, without the good/bad "like/dislike" polarization, so I'm voting to reopen now.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

in other words, has anything been done to the compiler to allow for a 'special case' the STL needed to work?

No.

It was all implemented as 'pure' C++ code, using the magic of templates.

There has been some work done to compilers to improve the STL (I'm thinking about various optimisations) but otherwise, no, you could write the entire STL if you really wanted. Some people did - [STLPort](http://www.stlport.org/) is an implementation that didn't have the backing of any compiler manufacturer.

Comment: Well, most compilers needed to brush up their standard compliance... but, yeah.

Comment: "With C++, the magic WAS ALREADY THERE.", +1

Comment: -1: This is no longer correct. See the other answers.

Answer (score 40):

Like gbjbaanb correctly said, the STL can be implemented in plain C++, without relying on any kind of compiler "magic".

However, if you go digging in the STL source code for your compiler, you'll probably see code that either isn't standard, or which you're not supposed to write yourself.

The STL can be implemented entirely in standard C++, but that doesn't mean compiler writers aren't allowed to improve it occasionally, using compiler-specific extensions. For example, they might insert non-standard code that ensures better error messages, or perhaps works around some flaw in their compiler, or maybe enables special optimizations by using extra features of that specific compiler.

They also consistently use names that you're not allowed to use. For example, template parameters are typically named something like `_Type`, which, since it starts with an underscore followed by a capital letter, is *reserved for the implementation*. The standard library is allowed to use them, but you and I are not. So if you were going to write your own STL implementation, you would have to make some minor changes, but that's not because of any magic, just a way to avoid name clashes between the standard library and user code.

Comment: Very nice answer! I'll let people vote for a while before I decide which answer to accept:-)

Comment: Note that the "reserved" names are reserved by policy.  This is not enforced by the compiler.  You could use them if you wanted.  As Jalf mentions, using these names runs the risk that your code will have name clashes with the libraries included in your compiler (or another one when someone else tried to compile your code), so obviously using them is a bad idea.

Comment: yup (I guess I should have mentioned that, but now you did such a good job of it, so +1 to you instead :))

Comment: @Tomalak: really? Which part of the STL cannot be implemented without "compiler magic"? And may I remind you of your usual stupid argument that STL is a SGI library from 20 years ago? To the best of my knowledge, *it has not changed*. So by your definition, my answer is **most definitely** correct. For the rest of us, it is a bit more iffy, because the rest of us use "STL" to refer to a subset of the standard library, and there are a number of standard library features in C++11 which require compiler "magic". But is there overlap between those features and the "STL" part? I don't think so.

Comment: If you have changed your mind, and are now willing to use "STL" to refer to a part of the standard library like the rest of the world's C++ developers, that's great, but you'll still need to tell me which of the parts of the C++11 standard library that require compiler magic should be considered part of the STL. Are type traits part of the STL? I don't think so, but you may feel differently, and some type traits do require such magic.

Comment: @Tomalak: seriously though, I know a few type traits require special compiler intervention to work, are they what you're thinking of?

Comment: @jalf: Yes. I was thinking of the C++11 stdlib and got a bit carried away. Suitably ashamed.

Comment: @Tomalak: well, which parts of the stdlib? The only case I can think of is type traits, but there might be others. I'm just curious what you had in mind. :)

Comment: @jalf: Covered pretty well in the other answers

Answer (score 16):

As others have said, the STL is implementable in pure standard C++98.  What hasn't been said is that the development of the STL was concurrent with the development of the C++ template mechanism, and largely drove the inclusion of certain features.  I believe that [Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL, aka Koenig Lookup)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), template template parameters, and default template arguments all came to C++ to serve Stepanov's STL development.

So, with STL, they moved the magic into the language itself.  Nice that the standards committee recognized that if those features were useful for what would become the standard library, they might be useful for the rest of us as well!

Comment: +1: Thanks for the history lesson!

Comment: If memory serves, ADL was separate (and even predates the proposal to standardize STL).

Comment: @Jerry--I suspect you're right.  I'm away from any relevant reference materials right now so I can't confirm.  Maybe somebody can dig up a comprehensive list?

Answer (score 14):

If by STL you mean only the template portion of the C++ Standard Library, then it is perfectly possible to implement it without any "magic". Whether each given implementation actually uses any "magic" is a different question (there are portions of STL where "magic" would help, but not absolutely required).

Now, if you are talking about the entire C++ Standard Library, then it does indeed have a bit of "magic" in it. The classic example would be the library-provided `::operator new` and `::operator delete` implementations. We often call them "overloadable" in everyday language, while formally they are *replaceable*. The C++ language does not offer such functionality to the user. The user cannot write a replaceable function.

Another example would be the `offsetof` macro (inherited from the C Standard Library). While it is usually implemented in "pure C", the popular implementation is actually illegal from the pedantic point of view (causes undefined behavior). I haven't seen any formally legal implementations of `offsetof`, so I'm not sure whether they are even possible.

Another example would be (again, inherited from C) the macros for working with variable arguments. They obviously cannot be implemented in pure C or C++.

Comment: +1: Shame this answer doesn't have more upvotes.

Comment: 'causes undefined behaviour'... there's plenty of places where that can be true, operator++ springs immediately to mind. So it's not illegal, just unadvised. And of course you cannot replace the default operator new, you can replace its functionality for your code. In all cases, nothing in this answer is 'magic' - ie special stuff that you cannot use in any form, special stuff that is only available to the just the compiler writer and no-one else.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Not true. Again, the standard library provides an implementations of `::operator new(size_t)`. You can write your own implementation of `::operator new(size_t)`, which will take over. It is not possible to implement anything like that in the user code. Having two external functions with the same signature will result in an error (ODR violation). The fact that you can do it for `::operator new(size_t)` is pure "magic".

Comment: Everything in my answer refers to magic. Relying on undefined behavior  in all cases is only possible through compiler specifics, which is a kind of magic (I don't understand what you mean by your `operator++` reference). In fact, GCC compiler switched from "undefined" implementation of `offsetof` to an explicitly magical implementation through `__builtin_offsetof`.

Answer (score 11):

I'm pretty sure some `type_traits` require compiler magic, for example `has_trivial_constructor`, `has_virtual_destructor` or `is_pod`.

Comment: Well, if that's true, I'd certainly like to know it! Does anybody know if these can be implemented in pure C++?

Comment: well, those aren't in the current version of the standard. They are scheduled for inclusion in C++0x (and quickly skimming the draft didn't yield any info on how they might be implemented, so you may be right that they require compiler magic to implement -- on the other hand, their only purpose then is to *expose* this compiler magic so ordinary developers may use it. They don't keep it to themselves like @Job's Java examples do.)

Comment: I took a quick look at tr1 in which these are included. It seems the standard defines things that cannot be implemented in pure C++ as undefined behavior (please correct me if I'm wrong). For example, `is_pod` may return false negatives.

Comment: Yes in C++0x there will be a few type traits that require compiler support, but I can't recall which ones. Those need Compiler support BECAUSE there is no way to implement them in pure C++.

Comment: @Job: that's TR1 though. the TR1 versions are library-only because they're basically adopted from Boost. They weren't basically the closest you could get without compiler support. C++0x takes it one step further and provides versions of these type traits that actually work correctly in *all* cases. And that can only be done through some unspecified form of compiler support.

Answer (score 7):

`std::initializer_list` needs compiler support and cannot be reimplemented as another class (as far as I know), though I'm not sure if it counts since it's in c++0x.

Answer (score 5):

C++0x is going to standardise some *de facto* "magic" type traits.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2984.htm

"Additional Type Traits for C++0x"

This contains a few remarks such as "XXXX is believed to require compiler support."

See also

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Type-Traits.html#Type-Traits

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177194(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

As "gbjbaanb" rightly said, there is no magic involved in the implementation of STL. It is written in pure C++. You could implement it yourself but has been made readily available as a library to make your life simpler.

Answer (score -2):

STL is standard (Standard Template Library). The standard specifies the requirements for STL implementations. From the usage point of view, there is no "magic", no special dependencies you have to take care of. It can be used on any major C++ compilers, on all platforms supported by those compilers.

Comment: But my question is whether the implementation of the STL itself needs any "magic" from the compiler.

Comment: @Job: It needs a good standards conformant compiler.

Comment: @Job: To support what has been said already: The **Magic** required from the compiler is **to be compliant to the implementation requirements** of STL, which is almost **any C++ compiler** out there and, aehm, which **complies to it**. Any old version of C++ compilers would not be able to handle the STL, almost any newer C++ compiler would. So thats like **Co-Evolution**.

Comment: @chubsdad: Good standards conformant compiler can be considered magic :) ...

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced compiler is indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: Actually, the "Standard" in "Standard Template Library" has nothing to do with the actual C++ Standard, which contains the "C++ Standard Library".