# Which <type_traits> cannot be implemented without compiler hooks?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

C++11 provides standard `<type_traits>`.

Which of them are *impossible* to implement without compiler hooks?

- Note 1: by compiler hook I mean any non-standard language feature such as `__is_builtin...`.
- Note 2: a lot of them can be implemented without hooks (see chapter 2 of  [C++ Template Metaprogramming](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/) and/or chapter 2 of [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)).
- Note 3: [spraff answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573768/is-there-magic-in-the-stl/6276081#6276081) in this previous question cites [N2984](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2984.htm) where some type traits contain the following note: *is believed to require compiler support* (thanks sehe).

Comment: @rightfold `is_void` does not seem to need a lot of magic :)

Comment: @Johan Just out of genuine curiosity, how would you implement `is_void`?

Comment: Now the question is whether a "hook" must be compiled into your compiler, or whether it can be provided as part of your toolchain's stdlib implementation. At that point, of course, it's just code. See what I mean?

Comment: I thought that `std::is_pod<T>` can be implemented _without_ a compiler hook! Something along the lines of not being a pointer or a reference but a viable argument for a variable argument list or something.

Comment: @H2CO3: It's trivial: `template <typename> struct is_void: std::true_type {}; template <> struct is_void<void>: false_type {};`

Comment: @H2CO3 I've checked [there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_void) to have a reliable implementation before answering, and here it relies on [integral_constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant), [is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and [remove_cv](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) the 3 of them being implementable without compiler magic.

Comment: Maybe relevant: [N2518 -- Compiler support for type traits](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2518.html)

Comment: @DietmarKühl trivial but no so :) It need to handle "cv" also.

Comment: Actually, an answer to this question would need to *prove* that it is impossible for *each* of the > 70 type traits to be implemented w/o compiler support.

Comment: @Johan It's easy enough to add specialisations for all possible qualifiers.

Comment: @Johan: fair enough, there need to be three more specializations or some hackery removing the qualifiers. The basic principle stays the same.

Comment: @H2CO3: just specialize the possibilities, surely? `template<typename T> struct is_void : integral_constant<bool, false> {};`, and then for V equal to each cv-qualified version of `void` (so, 4 specializations) `template<> struct is_void<V> : integral_constant<bool, true> {};`. For `integral_constant` in "pure" C++ without `<type_traits>` see the possible implementation at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant

Comment: @hvd Indeed but I prefer the cppreference version using `remove_cv`. :)

Comment: @DietmarKühl Passing non-"POD" class types to an ellipsis is conditionally-supported, [expr.call]/7.

Comment: [is_enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) ?

Comment: `is_polymorphic` comes to mind, as does `underlying_type`, and `is_bind_expression`.

Comment: @gnzlbg It might be better to ask the question *which of the type traits **can** be implemented w/o compiler support*, as you'd just have to provide an exemplary implementation.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Maybe it's possible to check if the type is a valid non-type template parameter: an enum is, but a class is not. So you could check if it's not an integral type but a valid non-type template parameter.

Comment: @KerrekSB `boost` has a "non-portable" check `is_polymorphic` by testing the size of a derived class after adding a virtual function.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: for what it's worth, pointer types *are* POD.

Comment: @DyP: Didn't we just discuss earlier that this doesn't work for non-polymorphic classes with virtual bases?

Comment: @KerrekSB *You* seem to have discussed that issue, I didn't participate in that discussion ;) But yes, it indeed seems to be a problem.

Comment: `is_function` can't be written in standard C++ because of `extern "C"` and other language linkages.

Comment: @Simple functions have the special property that adding `const` to them doesn't change the type. This can be exploited in combination with `is_reference`, since functions aren't references.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have written up a complete answer [here](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/from-scratch/blob/master/include/scratch/bits/type-traits/compiler-magic.md) — it's a work in progress, so I'm giving the authoritative hyperlink even though I'm cutting-and-pasting the text into this answer.

Also see libc++'s former documentation page on [Type traits intrinsic design](https://html-preview.github.io/?url=https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/f60ea691a94b3b4c28f2ff85a4520562f4110810/libcxx/www/type_traits_design.html) (mirrored in Apple's old docs [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-700.0.72/src/projects/libcxx/www/type_traits_design.html)).

### is_union

`is_union` queries an attribute of the class that isn't exposed through any other means;
in C++, anything you can do with a class or struct, you can also do with a union. This
includes inheriting and taking member pointers.

### is_aggregate, is_literal_type, is_pod, is_standard_layout, has_virtual_destructor

These traits query attributes of the class that aren't exposed through any other means.
Essentially, a struct or class is a "black box"; the C++ language gives us no way to
crack it open and examine its data members to find out if they're all POD types, or if
any of them are `private`, or if the class has any constexpr constructors (the key
requirement for `is_literal_type`).

### is_abstract

`is_abstract` is an interesting case. The defining characteristic of an abstract
class type is that you cannot get a value of that type; so for example it is
ill-formed to define a function whose parameter or return type is abstract, and
it is ill-formed to create an array type whose element type is abstract.
(Oddly, if `T` is abstract, then SFINAE will apply to `T[]` but not to `T()`. That
is, it is acceptable to create the *type* of a function with an abstract return type;
it is ill-formed to define an *entity* of such a function type.)

So we can get very close to a correct implementation of `is_abstract` using
this SFINAE approach:

```
template<class T, class> struct is_abstract_impl : true_type {};
template<class T> struct is_abstract_impl<T, void_t<T[]>> : false_type {};

template<class T> struct is_abstract : is_abstract_impl<remove_cv_t<T>, void> {};
```

However, there is a flaw! If `T` is itself a template class, such as `vector<T>`
or `basic_ostream<char>`, then merely forming the type `T[]` is acceptable; in
an unevaluated context this will *not* cause the compiler to go instantiate the
body of `T`, and therefore the compiler will not detect the ill-formedness of
the array type `T[]`. So the SFINAE will *not* happen in that case, and we'll
give the wrong answer for `is_abstract<basic_ostream<char>>`.

This quirk of template instantiation in unevaluated contexts is the sole reason
that modern compilers provide `__is_abstract(T)`.

### is_final

`is_final` queries an attribute of the class that isn't exposed through any other means.
Specifically, the base-specifier-list of a derived class is not a SFINAE context; we can't
exploit `enable_if_t` to ask "can I create a class derived from `T`?" because if we
cannot create such a class, it'll be a hard error.

### is_empty

`is_empty` is an interesting case. We can't just ask whether `sizeof (T) == 0` because
in C++ no type is ever allowed to have size 0; even an empty class has `sizeof (T) == 1`.
"Emptiness" is important enough to merit a type trait, though, because of the Empty Base
Optimization: all sufficiently modern compilers will lay out the two classes

```
struct Derived : public T { int x; };

struct Underived { int x; };
```

identically; that is, they will not lay out any space in `Derived` for the empty
`T` subobject. This suggests a way we could test for "emptiness" in C++03, at least
on all sufficiently modern compilers: just define the two classes above and ask
whether `sizeof (Derived) == sizeof (Underived)`. Unfortunately, as of C++11, this
trick no longer works, because `T` might be final, and the "final-ness" of a class
type is not exposed by any other means! So compiler vendors who implement `final`
must also expose something like `__is_empty(T)` for the benefit of the standard library.

### is_enum

`is_enum` is another interesting case. Technically, we could implement this type trait
by the observation that if our type `T` is *not* a fundamental type, an array type,
a pointer type, a reference type, a member pointer, a class or union, or a function
type, then by process of elimination it must be an enum type. However, this deductive
reasoning breaks down if the compiler happens to support any other types not falling
into the above categories. For this reason, modern compilers expose `__is_enum(T)`.

A common example of a supported type not falling into any of the above categories
would be `__int128_t`. libc++ actually detects the presence of `__int128_t` and includes
it in the category of "integral types" (which makes it a "fundamental type" in the above
categorization), but our simple implementation does not.

Another example would be `vector int`, on compilers supporting Altivec vector extensions;
this type is more obviously "not integral" but also "not anything else either", and most
certainly not an enum type!

### is_trivially_constructible, is_trivially_assignable

The triviality of construction, assignment, and destruction are all attributes of the
class that aren't exposed through any other means. Notice that with this foundation
we don't need any additional magic to query the triviality of *default* construction,
*copy* construction, *move* assignment, and so on. Instead,
`is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>` is implemented in terms of
`is_trivially_constructible<T, const T&>`, and so on.

### is_trivially_destructible

For historical reasons, the name of this compiler builtin is not `__is_trivially_destructible(T)`
but rather `__has_trivial_destructor(T)`. Furthermore, it turns out that the builtin
evaluates to `true` even for a class type with a deleted destructor! So we first need
to check that the type is destructible; and then, if it is, we can ask the magic builtin
whether that destructor is indeed trivial.

### underlying_type

The underlying type of an enum isn't exposed through any other means. You can get close
by taking `sizeof(T)` and comparing it to the sizes of all known types, and by asking
for the signedness of the underlying type via `T(-1) < T(0)`; but that approach still
cannot distinguish between underlying types `int` and `long` on platforms where those
types have the same width (nor between `long` and `long long` on platforms where *those*
types have the same width).

Comment: The "Type traits intrinsic design" link does not work. Could you please update it?

Answer (score 23):

Per lastest [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/intrinsics.html) which is also a bit old but I think it's valid still

### Support for Compiler Intrinsics

There are some traits that can not be implemented within the current C++ language: to make these traits "just work" with user defined types, some kind of additional help from the compiler is required. Currently (April 2008) Visual C++ 8 and 9, GNU GCC 4.3 and MWCW 9 provide at least some of the the necessary intrinsics, and other compilers will no doubt follow in due course.

The Following traits classes always need compiler support to do the right thing for all types (but all have safe fallback positions if this support is unavailable):

```
is_union
is_pod
has_trivial_constructor
has_trivial_copy
has_trivial_move_constructor
has_trivial_assign
has_trivial_move_assign
has_trivial_destructor
has_nothrow_constructor
has_nothrow_copy
has_nothrow_assign
has_virtual_destructor
```

The following traits classes can't be portably implemented in the C++ language, although in practice, the implementations do in fact do the right thing on all the compilers we know about:

```
is_empty
is_polymorphic
```

The following traits classes are dependent on one or more of the above:

```
is_class
```