# Possible to implement is_pod type trait in C++03 using SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, c++03

According to "[Which <type_traits> cannot be implemented without compiler hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181702/which-type-traits-cannot-be-implemented-without-compiler-hooks)", it's not possible to implement is_pod in C++03 without compiler intrinsics.  I thought of a possible way, though: C++03 does not allow unions that have members with a nontrivial constructor.  Is it possible to use SFINAE to detect this without throwing a compiler error?

I tried the following and many variants, and couldn't get it to work.  It always either throws an error or returns invalid answers.

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class is_pod
{
  template <typename U, void (U::*)()> struct Check;
  template <typename U> union Union { U u; void member(); };
  template <typename U> static char func(Check<Union<U>, &Union<U>::member> *);
  template <typename U> static char (&func(...))[2];
public:
  enum { value = sizeof(func<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};

struct Meow { };

struct Purr { Purr() { } };

int main()
{
  std::printf("%d\n", is_pod<Meow>::value);
  std::printf("%d\n", is_pod<Purr>::value);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I think that podness detection needs compiler support. SFIANEing that could be a solution? I don't know yet, let me try. Is it working in your case?

Comment: @GermánDiago: Nope; the code above does not work.

Comment: Then, that is why it is an intrinsic :D