# Why is there no language support in C++ for all C++ standard library type traits?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, language-lawyer, std

In C++ it is [impossible to implement certain C++ standard library type traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181702/which-type-traits-cannot-be-implemented-without-compiler-hooks) without compiler intrinsics, using the C++ language only. Traits deal directly with C++ types. According to §17.6.1.3.2 freestanding implementations of the C++ standard library must implement `<type_traits>`. Doesn't this effectively mean that the C++ standard requires non-standard language extensions/compiler intrinsics from all compilers which support want to support freestanding C++ standard library implementations?

**Why were such type traits allowed into the standard without support in the core language?**

Comment: .. because they are of uttermost importance?

Comment: @Columbo lol, fair enough.

Comment: The C++ standard requires that "#include <type_traits>" results in the standard library traits being defined. How that actually happens, it's up to the compiler. It's completely compliant for an implementation not to have any "type_traits" header file anywhere, but have the compiler hardcode this include statement to "activate" all the type traits, in the compliant manner.

Comment: To me, this is not much different to other library functions.  For example, you can't implement opening files yourself only using what is defined in the core language.

Comment: @VaughnCato It is different, because it does not have to interface with the execution enviroment, but instead deals with compile-time introspection and metaprogramming.

Comment: But why is that relevant?  Why is it important to be able to implement those traits yourself?

Comment: @VaughnCato What other options does a freestanding C++ standard library have to implement these?

Comment: Are you thinking that "freestanding" means that it is compiler-independent?

Comment: @VaughnCato No I'm not. Are you picking on me? It's difficult to tell.

Comment: Not at all.  "freestanding" means that execution can take place without an operating system, so I don't see why it being freestanding means that it can only use core language features.

Comment: @VaughnCato That is one of the reasons I'm asking this questions. It makes writing portable implementations difficult if not impossible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108038/discussion-between-vaughn-cato-and-jotik).

Comment: The core language and the standard library are interdependent. E.g. the core language `typeid` operator depends on the standard library `<typeinfo>` header, which is implementation specific. The old `offsetof` macro from C can't be implemented in a portable way. The `<type_traits>` header is also implementation specific, but that's not more of a problem.

Comment: Just to answer the "why", experimental type traits were long part of the Boost library. Some ingenious compiler-specific hacks, together with compiler sniffing, made it possible to provide largely portable versions of apparently impossible-to-implement traits. The Boost implementations proved that the traits were desirable and implementable. It was better to have them in the standard library. This could be done without extending the core language. The smallest amount of additions to the standard, adopting (mostly) only existing practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many aspects of the C++ standard library which *cannot* be implemented without support from the compiler. For example, `type_info`. A "freestanding C++ library" implementation can't provide such a type, since it is the result of a keyword-based expression: `typeid`. The only people who could provide such a thing are compiler writers, since the compiler is the one who has to generate those objects.

The same is true of many other elements of the standard library. `exception_ptr`, `current_exception(s)`, `initializer_list`, etc. There's a whole *chapter* of this stuff in the C++ standard.

Not all components of the standard library can be implemented without compiler support. Type traits are simply one more thing which a freestanding C++ library cannot implement. Not in ISO standard C++.

As for why they didn't provide the tools needed to implement them? Because that would have taken more time. Note that reflection isn't even a fully-formed TS yet, while type-traits have been standard for 5 years now.

It is difficult to specify general tools like reflection. To know exactly what behavior you need and how it should be provided. It's much easier to look at common usage patterns (as exemplified by Boost) and just use them. Type-traits are the low-hanging fruit of reflection.