# How does std::is_polymorphic identify polymorphism?

Tags: c++, std

I tried to understand the working of `std::is_polymorphc` in C++.
This is defined in `type_traits.h`:

```
template <class _Ty>
struct is_polymorphic : bool_constant<__is_polymorphic(_Ty)> {}; // determine whether _Ty is a polymorphic type

template <class _Ty>
_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool is_polymorphic_v = __is_polymorphic(_Ty);
```

I am not able to find the source code for `__is_polymorphic`.
Could someone help me understand how `__is_polymorphic` works ?

Comment: In [dcoumentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic) there is **Possible implementation** section.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In this case the type trait is implementable with just the core language, so I don't think the duplicate applies.

Comment: Let the duplicate be there as people might see that post too as it is related

Comment: It's not a dupe. As a related question it's place is in the comments. So here it is: [Why is there no language support in C++ for all C++ standard library type traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374178/why-is-there-no-language-support-in-c-for-all-c-standard-library-type-traits)

Comment: A class is polymorphic if it has a vtable (base class declares virtual functions). It is something the compiler needs to know anyway so that gives the compiler intrinsic something to work from.

Comment: @PepijnKramer a vtable is just one possible (and common) way to implement polymorphism. The C++ standard does not require, or even know about, vtables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__is_polymorphic` is a reserved keyword, so it's built-in to the compiler  i.e. it's not implemented in library, it's implemented directly in the compiler. So, there is no source code to see, unless you look at the compiler's source code.

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic), you can see a possible implementation:

> ```
> namespace detail {
>
> template <class T>
> std::true_type detect_is_polymorphic(
>     decltype(dynamic_cast<const volatile void*>(static_cast<T*>(nullptr)))
> );
> template <class T>
> std::false_type detect_is_polymorphic(...);
>
> } // namespace detail
>
> template <class T>
> struct is_polymorphic : decltype(detail::detect_is_polymorphic<T>(nullptr)) {};
> ```

This works by using the fact that `dynamic_cast` requires a polymorphic type in order to compile. `detect_is_polymorphic` is an overloaded function that uses SFINAE to check if `dynamic_cast` is valid on `T`.

Comment: Can you speak to why that proposed implementation works? I had no idea you could do `is_polymorphic` in pure C++, and I'd be curious to know why that cast detects the behavior we want.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It works because `dynamic_cast<void*>` is defined to only work on polymorphic types.  So this uses that fact along with the overload resolution rules so that for polymorphic types the first `detect_is_polymorphic` overload is chosen, but for non-polymorphic types it's SFINAE'd away and the second is chosen.

Answer (score 4):

With magic. I know, it's unsatisfying, but that's the answer. Most of `type_traits` is compiler-level magic. The C++ compiler knows that when it sees something like `is_polymorphic`, it should look through the list of methods available to the argument class (which is not something you can do as a C++ programmer, it's something only the compiler can do) and does the check via an ad-hoc method.