# How does the std::is_union implementation work?

Tags: c++, language-implementation

I'm currently going through the C++ standard library in some more detail, and I was wondering how the implementation of `std::is_union` works. In libcxx (LLVM), apart from directly using a possibly built-in `__is_union`, it is defined as

```cpp
template <class _Tp> struct __libcpp_union : public false_type {};
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_union
    : public __libcpp_union<typename remove_cv<_Tp>::type> {};
```

Similarly, STLPort, although quite old implements it even more minimalistic:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct is_union
{ };
```

This seems to always resolve to `std::false_type`, or even worse, an empty struct, but it doesn't; how is this achieved?
In another question, an answer stated that [`is_union` can't be implemented without compiler hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181702/which-type-traits-cannot-be-implemented-without-compiler-hooks/20182146#20182146), but wouldn't this mean that libcxx, STLPort, and probably all major implementations aren't portable to any compiler that doesn't automagically make it work?

Comment: You're not expected to mix and match compilers and standard libraries; they're meant to be a matched set.

Comment: You didn't show the full implementation from either of these libraries. Both of them have `#ifdef`s that check for compiler intrinsics.

Comment: STLPort was something from 10 years ago, from what I remember.  Is there actually a current version of this?  It became basically obsolete due to all major compilers having support for the STL.

Comment: If a compiler purports to be compatible with C++11, then it's the responsibility of the compiler vendor to have `std::is_union`.  Otherwise, many programmers would consider the compiler broken (if the vendor says it supports C++ 11), or is just not a C++11 compiler (maybe C++03 or 98),

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all of the std library can be implemented in C++.

You skipped the tests for various intrinsics.

There is no way to implment `is_union` without intrinsics, essentially.

The `std` library is **not** a library that ships with C++, it is part of the language.  `#include <vector>` permits certain code to work; no `vector` header need exist, just the state of the C++ program has to change after the directive.

In practice (by design) it is written and implemented in C++ as a relatively conventional library with the help from intrinsics, and written with reserved tokens to avoid preprocessor conflicts (the `__` and `_Ty` variable  names, for example).